# Bash, call a function sourced from a script?

Tags: bash, function

Say I have 2 scripts

test1.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
. ./test2.sh
foo
```

test2.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
foo(){
  echo "bar"
}
```

If I call first script it is ok

```
$ ./test1.sh
bar
```

But if I try to call `foo` after that it will not work.

```
$ foo
bash: foo: command not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I source test1.sh it gives the desired result.

```bsh
$ . test1.sh
bar

$ foo
bar
```

Answer (score 10):

When you execute `./test1.sh`, a subprocess is spawned. When `test1.sh` sources `test2.sh`, only the context of that subprocess is modified when `foo()` is defined. As soon as `test1.sh` completes, the subprocess terminates and your interactive shell has no knowledge of `foo()`.

Answer (score 3):

If you call `source test2.sh` you will get the result you want. 
If you want to be able to call foo whenever you start new terminal, place its definition in .bashrc or .profile file.