# How to call a function when a sh file is called using terminal

Tags: linux, bash, function, terminal, sh

I have a code in a file named main.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
function hello() {
  echo $1
}
```

I want to call it from command line like this:

```
main hello teddy
```

and it should output like hello teddy.
 Is that possible?. If yes, Please tell me.
**Thank you in advance**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash, call a function sourced from a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330753/bash-call-a-function-sourced-from-a-script)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible depending on where you define the function. There are several [bash startup](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) files which are run on startup. For example, `.bashrc`:

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, Bash reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists.

So if you define your function in your `.bashrc` you will be able to run it just as if you had explicitly defined it using the shell.